# Установка instagram-python

Tags: python, api, instagram

Возникает ошибка при установке instagram-python.
Не устанавливается pycurl? "вручную" отдельно устанавливается (пробовал переустановить pycurl, а потом python-instagram) ошибка осталась.

````
Collecting instagram-python
  Using cached instagram-python-1.4.tar.gz (25 kB)
Collecting pycurl==7.43.0
  Using cached pycurl-7.43.0.tar.gz (182 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 10:
     command: 'c:\users\xzc\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\XZC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ogpchbik\\pycurl\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\XZC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ogpchbik\\pycurl\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\XZC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-gid31khx'
         cwd: C:\Users\XZC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ogpchbik\pycurl\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 10: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.```
````

Comment: Похожая проблема здесь: https://qna.habr.com/q/686114, также, можете попробовать `pip install module_name --no-cache-dir`

Comment: Оба способа попробовал тоже самое - ошибка.

Comment: Какая у вас версия установленного сейчас Python?

Answer (score 0):

> Не устанавливается pycurl?

Я тоже так думал, через некоторое время походов по интернету оказалось, что это не так.

Я нашёл данный модуль на [GitHub](https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram) и там было написано, что он требует некоторые зависимости.
А именно:

- httplib2
- simplejson
- six
- pycurl уже был установлен

После установки всех зависимостей команда `pip install instagram-python` была успешно выполнена!

На всякий случай оставлю [ссылку](https://pypi.org/project/instagram-python/#files) на instagram-python на сайте pip.

P.S. спасибо за вопрос, я хотел собирать список ошибок pip и их исправление, и вы подсказали ещё одну : )

Comment: Установились httplib2 и simplejson, six уже был установлен и обновлён. Установка instagram-python также заканчивается с ошибкой. 
Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl может здесь искать проблему?

Comment: @Athreem попробуйте установить по ссылке с github

Comment: Пробовал и локально установить результат такой же (ошибка не полная)
C:\Users\XZC>pip install C:/instagram-python-1.4
Processing c:\instagram-python-1.4
Collecting pycurl==7.43.0
  Using cached pycurl-7.43.0.tar.gz (182 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 10: